# Error with PHP validation

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am creating a basic auction site and got quite far with help from this community. I am near finishing this now but having a slight issue with server side validation.

Auctions are listed on a PHP page with html and PHP, PHP runs a MySQL query and then lists the results. Example here:

```
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * From auction WHERE category = 'Bathroom' ORDER BY ID DESC");


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    echo "<form name='auction' id='auction" . $row['ID'] . "'>
            <input type='hidden' name='id' value='" . $row['ID'] . "' />
            <div class='auction-thumb'>
                <div class='auction-name'>" . $row['Item'] . "</div>";
            echo "<img class='auction' src='" . $row['ImagePath'] . "' />";
            echo "<div class='auction-bid'>Current Bid: £<div class='nospace' id='" . $row['ID'] . "'>" . $row['CurrentBid'] . "</div></div>";
            echo "<div class='auction-bid'>Your Name: <input type='text' class='bidder' name='bidname' autocomplete='off'/></div>";
            echo "<div class='auction-bid'>Your Bid: <input type='text' class='auction-text' name='bid' autocomplete='off'/></div>";
            echo "<div class='auction-bid'><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Place Bid!' /></div>";
            echo "<div class='bid-success' id='bid" . $row['ID'] . "'>Bid placed!</div>";
    echo "</div></form>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
```

Once the user clicks the submit button, the following jQuery is executed:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('form[name="auction"]').submit(function(){
            var id = $(this).find('input[name="id"]').val();
            var bidname = $(this).find('input[name="bidname"]').val();
            var bid = $(this).find('input[name="bid"]').val();
            var currentbid = $('#'+id).text();

            var itemdesc = $(this).find('.auction-name').text();

            bid = parseFloat(parseFloat(bid).toFixed(2));
            currentbid = parseFloat(parseFloat(currentbid).toFixed(2));



            if (bidname == '')
            {
                alert("No name!")
                return false;   
            }

        /*  if (bid > currentbid)
            {
                alert("Bid is greater than current bid");   
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Bid is too low!");
                return false;   
            }*/

            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "auction-handler.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {bidname: bidname, bid: bid, id: id, itemdesc: itemdesc},
            success: function(data){
                $('#bid'+id).fadeIn('slow', function () {
                    $(this).delay(1500).fadeOut('slow');

                });
                //$('#auction' + id).find('.nospace').html(currentbid);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("bid too low");
            }

        });
        return false;

        }); 
    });
```

If the code POSTS, the following PHP code is run on the handler page:

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

$bidname = $_POST['bidname'];
$bid = $_POST['bid'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
$itemdesc = $_POST['itemdesc'];



$highestbid = mysqli_fetch_row(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT CurrentBid from Auction WHERE ID = '$id'"));
    if ($bid <= $highestbid)
    {
        $_SESSION['errors']['bid'] = 'Sorry, but the bid is too low';
        echo json_encode($_SESSION['errors']);
        exit;
    }
    else
    {

$query = "UPDATE auction SET CurrentBid = '$bid', Bidder = '$bidname' WHERE ID = '$id'";

$query2 = "INSERT INTO auction_log (Item, Bid, Bidder) VALUES ('$itemdesc','$bid','$bidname')";



mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error());

mysqli_query($con, $query2) or die(mysqli_error());

mysqli_close($con);
```

I added some server side validation to make sure that the bid posted is higher than what is currently in the MySQL table.

The problem I am having is that I get the "Sorry, but the bid is too low" error no matter what bid I put in.

If I put a bid higher than the current bid, I get the error, if I put a bid in lower, I get the error.

Both ways I go about it also trigger the success section of the AJAX.

I feel like I'm missing something very simple, so if anyone could help that would be great.

I am not sure why it's being downvoted, I am just looking for some help.

Thanks

Comment: where are you clearing the session?

Comment: how are you updating this message after the ajax?

Comment: @madalinivascu Sorry I'm not sure where I would do it. Which message?

Comment: Check the value in `$highestbid` for debugging.

Comment: @Barnold the error man the error

Comment: on this line `error: function() {
                alert("bid too low");
            }`

Comment: @Sasikumar Hi, I am trying to with Firebug but it doesn't show `$highestbid` it only debugs the page with the auctions on, and shows me what has been posted.

Comment: You had provided the return data type as json so you need to return the data as json as your doing for `json_encode($_SESSION['errors']);`, then only you can see the value of `$highestbid`

Comment: `$highestbid = mysqli_fetch_row(...);` - this is an array. You can't compare arrays (meaningfully) so it fails. Also, holy crap there's a lot of security issues in your code...

Comment: @Sasikumar Ok so I have added this to my code `echo json_encode($highestbid)` and I get the following back: {"0":"26.00","CurrentBid":"26.00"} The current bid is correct, but im not sure why there's a 0 and which it shows it twice.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Ok how would I retrieve the record in a way that it isn't an array?

Comment: You have the array, just get the value from the array.

Comment: How can you be working on an “auction site”, and still write code that is wide open to SQL injection …?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've managed to do it. But I am facing the problem now where ajax always goes to the `error: function()` regardless of it passing server side validation.

Comment: @CBroe It's a personal project. I'm clearly still learning, and clearly this isn't going to be a public site. But thanks for the non-helpful response anyway.

Comment: you said in the question `"Both ways I go about it also trigger the success section of the AJAX".` .and here in comments you said `"ajax always goes to the error: function()"` do you trigger the success function or error function? what is the status code you get from this ajax?

Comment: Avoiding SQL Injection is the very first thing you need to learn.

Comment: @theaccountant Hi, actually it's very strange. If I submit with a bid that is higher than the current bid, it will post. But I will get the alert saying it's too low. If I bid lower than the current bid, it doesn't post, but instead shows me the PHP error `$_SESSION['errors']['bid'] = 'Sorry, but the bid is too low';`

Comment: @CBroe Ok, and I will learn it, but right now I am asking a specific question I need help on.

Comment: `$highestbidArray = mysqli_fetch_row(...); $highestbid = $highestbidArray['CurrentBid']` then compare the value.

Comment: @Sasikumar Got it thanks. However I am having a seperate issue now.

Answer (score 0):

The way that you're handling AJAX error is not very good because it only alerts you that you have an error, but you don't know what goes wrong.

In the AJAX object, replace the current error callback with one that logs the actual error to the console:

replace

```
error: function() {
                alert("bid too low");
            }
```

with

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
           }
```

and you'll know for sure what is the error

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, I get the following response: `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`. I'm not too sure what this means

Comment: Do you receive the same error in both cases (bid too low or bid higher)?

Comment: Yes I do, it works properly (i.e. if I post a higher bid, it updates MySQL, if i post a lower bid it does not) but I receive the same error regardless of it being too high or too low.

Comment: What I am struggling to understand is why the error part of the AJAX is called every single time, regardless or being successful or not.

Comment: From what i see on your AJAX request, the data that you're expecting has to be in JSON format (link here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). You get an error after posting a higher bid because you don't return a JSON response. After you close the db connection try echo json_encode(['response'=>'ok']). Also, if the bid is smaller, get rid of the exit() function, leave only the json response. this is the reason for the parse error